# Let Q(n) be the sum of digits of n. Prove that Q(n) = Q(2n) implies 9|n

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I don't know how to approach this question any hint would be appreciated .

Comment: Where did you come across this problem? Do you have access to any tools that you think might be helpful for questions like this?

Comment: I came across this question in an olympiad trainer book and The digit sum characteristic theorem might be helpful

Comment: Yes it did thanks @player3236

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
$$Q(n) \equiv n \pmod{9}$$

Therefore $Q(n)=Q(2n)$ implies
$$n \equiv 2n \pmod{9}$$

Comment: Oh thanks that 1st step was crucial

Comment: i have one more question pls answer it in this comment box only because otherwise i have to wait for 30 mis

Comment: Q) What is the fifth digit from the end of 5^5^5^5^5